# How to choose the bandwidth of a KDE in python

Tags: cross-validation, kernel-smoothing

Python's Sklearn module provides methods to perform Kernel Density Estimation. 
One of the challenges in Kernel Density Estimation is the correct choice of the kernel-bandwidth.

I have come across the following python-expression to select a bandwidth:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(kernel = 'gaussian'),{'bandwidth': np.linspace(0.1, 0.5, 20)}, cv = 5, iid = True)
```

Here, `GridSearchCV` is a method that performs K-Fold Cross-Validation. Here is how I understand it:

We split the data, whose density is to be estimated, into K subsets. We then train the Kernel-Density-Estimation Algorithm with the data points of K-1 subsets. And finally, we evaluate the accuracy of our found parameters on the remaining subset. We repeat the process K times, each time choosing a different subset for testing.

Now, here is my question: In the given python-expression: Which is the algorithm that `KernelDensity(kernel = 'gaussian')` makes use of? 
Is it a nearest-neighbor algorithm? Does this mean: We consider a data point and place a Gaussian onto it. We will now have a look at all the data points that fall within this Gaussian. From their values, we estimate the value of the data point that we have placed the Gaussian on.

Does anything that I am saying make sense?

Comment: Are you interested in knowing how KDE works on its own, given the bandwidth; or, how GridSearchCV decides on the best bandwidth? Your title and body ask different things I suppose.

Comment: @gunes: well, I want to know how KDE works. Or `KernelDensity()`. But I am also interested in knowing if my understanding of `GridSearchCV` is correct. Do you ask me to alter my question?

Comment: `kde.py` does not really do any bandwidth estimation; it uses a default value. The "big thing" it does is having an efficient way of finding the neighbours. Given that we have the proximity of the data-points in question we then place the Gaussian (or whatever kernel) on top.

Comment: @usεr11852: Can you explain the idea behind how `kde` finds its neighbours?

Comment: By default it is the [kd_tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) algorithm.

Comment: kde_tree seems to be just a datastructure tho, that is commonly used for nearest neighbour searches. .. so, how is nearest neighbour search performed in order to determine the kernel density out of a given set of data points? The wikipedia article formulates the nearest neighbour search problem as: "given a set S of points in a space M and a query point q ∈ M, find the closest point in S to q." So in my case, I consider all the data points within my gaussian kernel. Does `KernelDensity()` now apply a nearest neighbour search to find the k neighbours closest to my mid-point of the kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid search CV is sensible because having a PDF estimation with data of $K-1$ folds and testing on the holdout set, by calculating the data log-likelihood, i.e. $\sum \log \hat{p}(x_i)$, you can get an estimate of how good is your KDE.

Normally, for a given query point, KDE uses all the points in the data to estimate its density, i.e. $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum K_h(x-x_i)$, when the kernel has infinite support. However, distant points have negligible effect (e.g. adding $10^{-16}$ to $1$ for example), and to be effective/practical some number of neighbours are used, depending on your bandwidth. This can be done efficiently via data structures like *ball tree* or *kd tree* as @user11852 also pointed out.

Comment: ok, I think I get it now: `KernelDensity()` is simply estimating the density of the given data. This means: We place a Gaussian on each data point and then sum up all of these Gaussians. When normalizing by the number of data points, this should yield the PDF. Now, `GridSearchCV` is an algorithm that selects the optimal bandwidth of the Gaussians that `KernelDensity()` is going to use. To achieve this, `GridSearchCV` tries out a certain bandwidth and lets `KernelDensity()` estimate the pdf using K-1 folds. It then tests how good the KDE is on the last fold by computing the log-likelihood (?).

Comment: Exactly. Also GridSearchCV does this K times and averages the likelihood.

Comment: great, thx a lot, man! ... one last question: how is the log-likelihood a measure of how good the estimated pdf is? I mean, the log-likelihood tells me how likely it is to get a certain value within the test-data set. I will still have to compare this value with the actual number of times this value appears within this data set, won't I ?

Comment: Think about $p(x_i)$ as a probability (although it's not exactly). Your likelihood is $\prod p(x_i)$, or log-likelihood, $\sum \log p(x_i)$. So, if some sample value appears more than once, its likelihood will be multiplied more than once, so number of its appearance will be represented in the final data likelihood.

Comment: ok. Well, the log-likelihood function is computed from the test-fold, right? So is this function suppossed to equal the pdf that was estimated from the K-1 training folds? ... I'm just trying to understand how the log-likelihood from the test-fold is saying anything about the accuracy of the estimated pdf

Comment: you estimate a pdf from K-1 fold data, and evaluate likelihood of test fold. Do this K times, and average all log-likelihoods. There you get an average estimate of your data likelihood. If you get higher likelihoods for a bandwidth value, this means your data is explained better using it. Think likelihood as probability of event you have your data, the higher it is, the likely the bandwidth is able to explain the data.

Comment: @user503842: if you find this answer helpful you could consider upvoting it or even accept it if it addresses your question adequately. (It is +1 from me obviously!)